# directory service event log

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-event-log

Situation:
I have a need to examine Directory Service event logs for multiple servers once an hour.  In order to do this without crushing the DCs and not be bound by network speed I am copying the evtx file to a different machine.  The downside, the machine I am processing on does not have the AD Role on it nor can I have it installed, which means that tools like logparser.exe and PowerShell Get-WinEvent are unable to read the Message information in the log.

What I am seeking is a way to either read the message from the event log programmatically or be able to load the dlls/assemblies to facilitates said reading.  PowerShell strongly preferred as I am not a .NET developer.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just install a log monitoring solution that can monitor those logs in real-time, without the hassle of mucking around with scripts, setting up another DC (which you would most likely have to do) etc?

Comment: We are actually doing this for a short term only to gather information for a specific project.  If it were a long term situation, I would most certainly advocate for a solution such as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Get-WinEvent cmdlet, all of the message information is stored in a property called, properties.  A co-worker and I discovered this after a lot of poking around and guessing.

For those of you who use LogParser (which reads the event logs much faster btw) you can find the message in the Strings property.

Thank you to those who took a look and tried to assist!